# ITE 8686E Super IO sensor support

Tags: drivers, sensors, lm-sensors

Running `sudo sensors-detect` gives me following output:

```
Driver `to-be-written':
  * ISA bus, address 0xa40
    Chip `ITE IT8686E Super IO Sensors' (confidence: 9)
```

I have got [Gigabyte B450M](https://www.gigabyte.com/eu/Motherboard/B450M-DS3H-rev-10#kf) motherboard.

The `it87` does not provide support for this Super IO sensor (basing on my short research).

Can one give me a glipse how to proceeed with this issue? Is there any chance that I can provide support for this sensors on my own (assuming some programming skills)?

Comment: I have the same issue, maybe this discussion could help : https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/issues/71